# Azure Document Db Worker Role

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-cosmosdb

I am having problems getting the Microsoft.Azure.Documents library to initialize the client in an azure worker role.  I'm using Nuget Package 0.9.1-preview.

I have mimicked what was done in the [example for azure document](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-net/blob/master/tutorials/todo/src/DocumentDBRepository.cs)

When running locally through the emulator I can connect fine with the documentdb and it runs as expected.  When running in the worker role, I am getting a series of NullReferenceException and then ArgumentNullException.

[image]

The bottom System.NullReferenceException that is highlighted above has this call stack
[image]

so the nullReferenceExceptions start in this call at the new DocumentClient.

```
var endpoint = "myendpoint";
var authKey = "myauthkey";
var enpointUri = new Uri(endpoint);
DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(endpointUri, authKey);
```

Nothing changes between running it locally vs on the worker role other then the environment (obviously).

Has anyone gotten DocumentDb to work on a worker role or does anyone have an idea why it would be throwing null reference exceptions?  The parameters getting passed into the DocumentClient() are filled.

**UPDATE:**
I tried to rewrite it being more generic which helped at least let the worker role run and let me attached a debugger.  It is throwing the error on the new DocumentClient.  Seems like some security passing is null.  Both the required parameters on initialization are not null. Is there a security setting I need to change for my worker role to be able to connect to my documentdb?  (still works locally fine)

**UPDATE 2:**
I can get the instance to run in release mode, but not debug mode.  So it must be something to do with some security setting or storage setting that is misconfigured I guess?

It seems I'm getting System.Security.SecurityExceptions - only when using The DocumentDb - queues do not give me that error.  All Call Stacks for that error seem to be with System.Diagnostics.EventLog.  The very first Exception I see in the Intellitrace Summary is System.Threading.WaitHandleCannotBeOpenedException.

**More Info**
Intellitrace summary exception data:
[image]
[image]

top is the earliest and bottom is the latest (so System.Security.SecurityException happens first then the NullReference)

Comment: where are you attempting to init the DocumentClient? In OnStart, RunAsync in the Loop? 

also, where are your configuration settings stored?
if you deploy to Azure make sure the config settings are in the correct cscfg file (i.e. not in app.config)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution for me to get rid of the security exception and null reference exception was to disable intellitrace.  Once I did that, I was able to deploy and attach debugger and see everything working.

Not sure what is between the null in intellitrace and the DocumentClient, but hopefully it's just in relation to the nuget and it will be fixed in the next iteration.

Comment: This fixed it for me, still an issue 6 months later :(

Answer (score 3):

unable to repro.

I created a new Worker Role. Single instance. Added authkey & endoint config to cscfg.

Created private static DocumentClient at WorkerRole class level

Init DocumentClient in OnStart 
Dispose DocumentClient in OnStop

In RunAsync inside loop, 
execute a query Works as expected.

Test in emulator works. 
Deployed as Release to Production slot. works.
Deployed as Debug to Staging with Remote Debug. works. 
Attached VS to CloudService, breakpoint hit inside loop.

Working solution : http://ryancrawcour.blob.core.windows.net/samples/AzureCloudService1.zip

Comment: That's odd, I still get the same behavior with your solution.  All I do is swap out the Endpoint and AuthKey and then run it locally - works fine.  Then deploy it to staging and the role reports unhealthy with throwing the System.Null again.  The endpoint and authkey you used was from the Keys panel in the documentdb in the new portal.azure.com right?  I'll try starting from a fresh worker role and see if something got messed up in all my tests.

Comment: was also just going to mention, I can get queues to work in that worker role, so it must be something with my setup, whether security or something when publishing.

Comment: yup. I did nothing fancy at all. this is really weird why it fails in Debug only.

Comment: are you capturing any Diagnostics, Intellitrace, Perf counters on the Role?

Comment: I do have intellitrace data.  Basically I took a new project again and started fresh, added the storage nuget; did the client how you had it; the key and uri are there; and then deployed to unhealthy.  I'll update the question again with the intellitrace with 2 screenshots.  I'm at a loss since it seems to be just my setup somehow.  i'm going to try a different computer and see if  this visual studio has some issue.

Comment: Ok, so after trying a different computer and trying various things.  It turns out that when I enable intellitrace that's when I get the worker role into an unhealthy state.  If I just do remote debug it works fine and your example works and I see my dbs.  Could you try and enable intellitrace and see if it becomes unhealthy? The only change is checking enable intellitrace in advanced settings.

Comment: this is interesting. I wonder if that's a general issue with Worker Roles and Intellitrace. I will take a look.